# NLTK: Tuning LinearSVC classifier accuracy? - Looking for better approaches/advices

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

**Problem/Main objective/TLDR:** Train a classifier, then feed it a random review and get the correspondent predicted review rating (number of stars from 1 to 5) - only 60% accuracy! :(

I have a big dataset with around 48000 tech product reviews (from many different writers and from different products - here this is not so important (?)) and corresponding ratings (1 to 5 stars)
I randomly selected some reviews within each class:

- 1 star: 173 reviews (could not pick 1000 because there were 173)
- 2 stars: 1000 reviews
- 3 stars: 1000 reviews
- 4 stars: 1000 reviews
- 5 stars: 1000 reviews

Total: 4173 reviews - this data is organized in one file (all_reviews_labeled.txt) in tuple format, one review and rating for line:

- (‘review text’, ‘x star’)
- (‘review text’, ‘x star’)
- (‘review text’, ‘x star’)
- (‘review text’, ‘x star’)
- …

My 1st “dummie” aproach was:

1. Tokenize review text
2. POS tagging
3. Get most frequent bigrams that folowing some POS tags rules for
   most frequent trigrams (I have seen this rules - using this POS
   patterns in “Automatic Star-rating Generation from Text Reviews” -
   pag.7 - paper from Chong-U Lim, Pablo Ortiz and Sang-Woo Jun):

   ```
   for (w1,t1), (w2,t2), (w3,t3) in nltk.trigrams(text):
       if (t1 == 'JJ' or t1 == 'JJS' or t1 == 'JJR') and (t2 == 'NN' or t2 == 'NNS'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       elif (t1 == 'RB' or t1 == 'RBR' or t1 == 'RBS') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJR') and (t3 != 'NN' or t3 != 'NNS'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       elif (t1 == 'JJ' or t1 == 'JJS' or t1 == 'JJR') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS') and (t3 != 'NN' or t3 != 'NNS'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       elif (t1 == 'NN' or t1 == 'NNS') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS') and (t3 != 'NN' or t3 != 'NNS'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       elif (t1 == 'RB' or t1 == 'RBR' or t1 == 'RBS') and (t2 == 'VB' or t2 == 'VBD' or t2 == 'VBN' or t2 == 'VBG'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       elif (t1 == 'DT') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       elif (t1 == 'VBZ') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS'):
           bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
           bigrams.append(bi)
       else:
           continue
   ```
4. Extract features (here is where I have more doubts - should I
   only look for this two features?):

   ```
   features={}
   for bigram,freq in word_features:
       features['contains(%s)' % unicode(bigram).encode('utf-8')] = True
       features["count({})".format(unicode(bigram).encode('utf-8'))] = freq
   return features
   ```

   featuresets = [(review_features(review), rating) for (review, rating) in tuples_labeled_reviews]
5. Splits the training data into training size and testing size
   (90% training - 10% testing):

   ```
   numtrain = int(len(tuples_labeled_reviews) * 90 / 100)
   train_set, test_set = featuresets[:numtrain], featuresets[numtrain:]
   ```
6. Train SVMc:

   ```
   classifier = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
   classifier.train(train_set)
   ```
7. Evaluate the classifier:

   ```
   errors = 0
   correct = 0
   for review, rating in test_set:
       tagged_rating = classifier.classify(review)
       if tagged_rating == rating:
           correct += 1
           print("Correct")
           print "Guess: ", tagged_rating
           print "Correct: ", rating
       else:
           errors += 1
   ```

So far I get only 60% accuracy… 
What can I do to improve my prediction results? Is something before, some text/reviews preprocessing (like removing stopwords/punctuation?) that is missing? Could you suggest me some other approaches? I am still a bit confused if is really a classification problem or a regression one... :/

Please simple explanations, or give me a link to “machine learning for dummies”, or be my mentor, I promise to learn fast!
My background in machine learning/language processing/data mining is very light, I have played a couple of times with weka (Java), but now I need to stick with Python (nltk + scikit-learn)!

**EDIT:**

1. Now I am also extracting unigrams as features, unigrams POS-tagged as 'JJ', 'NN','VB' and 'RB'. It improved a little the accuracy to 65%.
2. I applied also do stemming and lemmatization in text before POS tagging. It improved the accuracy to +70%.

**EDIT 2:**

3. I have feed the classifier all my reviews, the 48000, split into 90% training and 10% testing and the accuracy was 91%.
4. Now I have 32000 new reviews (also labeled) and feed them all for testing and the mean accuracy was 62 % ... my confusion matrix is something like this image below (i divided by equal errors of +1/-1 star point, +2/-2, +3/-3 - because it is just an illustration):

[image]
What is happening? Why accuracy drops so much at 3 and 5 stars?

Comment: Well this question is a bit open and might get more chances of good answers @ [this site](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, to me your approach looks good, and a 60% accuracy on your first trial is not so bad (although I don't know how long it took you). (How do you measure accuracy? Since rates are 1 to 5, accuracy is when you make it exactly right? But then, the ones that are not right, are at least closed?) One thing you should definitively do is to look at some examples that are classified wrongly, and try to figure out why. Another thing, what accuracy you get @ training?

Comment: Whether this is a regression or classification problem depends on what you want to do with it: is it "more wrong" if the classifier predicts 1 star for a 5 star review or if it predicts 4 stars for this 5 star review? If so, then accuracy might not a good metric (as it does not distinguish between these cases). That's the most important thing to fix before working on preprocessing or tweaking the algorithm imho.

Comment: @Irnzcig how long it took me what? all the building strategy + training the classifier? I am in this about one week only =x --- training the classifier needs 3hours. I only verified the test accuracy, I will now verify for training. Thanks so much for your help/opinion

Comment: @Idirer you say that accuracy is not a good metric because it only measure the percentage of correct reviews labeled, right? I need one that focus on wrong ones to see if it is really wrong or aproximated? like give 4 stars to a 5star review, and not the extremes, like give 1 star to a 5star review... I have checked visually only and there is more errors in 1 point difference only

Comment: @Irnzcig in training i got 98% accuracy, just checked now

Comment: Do a cross validation on your training set. Not test on training. Testing on training is just a sanity check because you should always get optimized results when testing on training set.

Comment: @alvas thanks for your answer. I do not test with the training data.
Cross validation? I will see more about it, thanks

Comment: I have used all the dataset, the 48000 reviews, 90% training - 10% testing, with LinearSVC, looking at bigrams and adjectives only and get an accuracy of 93%, is it normal?

Comment: How can i see the most informative features within classes?

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding more features. For a task I had, to find the writer of a text between four authors, I used the following features:

- Sentence features

  - Average sentence length in words
  - Average sentence length in syllables
  - Average sentence length in characters
  - Long sentences percent
- Lexical features

  - Number of words
  - Hapaxes (words seen only once)
  - Dislegomena (words seen only two times)
  - Ratio of Dislegomena to Hapaxes
  - Average words length
  - Lexical diversity
  - YuleK
  - HeransC
  - GuiraudsR
  - Uber
  - Entropy
  - Relative entropy
  - 1lw .. 14lw (the frequency of words with one character, with two characters, ... with 14 characters)
- Character features

  - Percent of character a,
  - Percent of character b,
  - ...
- Words

  - Percent of each of the 50 most frequent words of the corpus

For every text, the above build it's features vector. I had used Discriminant Analysis in SPSS. Of course you can use SVM or other classifiers.

Comment: I have used all the dataset, the 48000 reviews, 90% training - 10% testing, with SVMc, looking at bigrams and adjectives only and get an accuracy of 93%, is it normal?

Comment: Try to cross validate using 5 to 10 folds to get more accurate results. In reviews, adjectives and specially in bigrams or trigrams carry much information. For example, we think "bad": negative, "good": positive. But, "not bad": positive, "not good": negative.

Comment: with cross validation 10fold. the mean accuracy was 98%, thanks @Aris F. for the suggestion